# ReactJs - Parsing JSON from call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks

I have a React form with multiple fields that need to be pre-filled with an async json call. I'm trying to set the value of the buttons with attributes from the main json but the data isn't available after load.

How would you access generic json values from an async call on load?

```
export function App() {
    const [values, setValues] = useState<any[]>([]);

    const [valueOne, setValueOne] = useState();
    const [valueTwo, setValueTwo] = useState();


    // gets called once, no dependencies, loads the grid data
    useEffect(() => {
        //returns
        //Object { valueOne: "N", valueTwo: "Y" }
        Service.getValues()
            .then(data => setValues(data)
            );

        //these are not setting 
        setValueOne(values.valueOne)
        setValueTwo(values.valueTwo)
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <ToggleButtonGroup size="sm" type="radio" name="testOne"
                                               value={valueOne}>
                                <ToggleButton id="tbg-radio-1" value={'Y'} variant={'outline-success'}>
                                    Running
                                </ToggleButton>
                                <ToggleButton id="tbg-radio-2" value={'N'} variant={'outline-danger'}>
                                    Suspended
                                </ToggleButton>
                            </ToggleButtonGroup>
                            
                            <ToggleButtonGroup size="sm" type="radio" name="testTwo"
                                                value={valueTwo}>
                                <ToggleButton id="tbg-radio-3" value={'Y'} variant={'outline-success'}>
                                    Running
                                </ToggleButton>
                                <ToggleButton id="tbg-radio-4" value={'N'} variant={'outline-danger'}>
                                    Suspended
                                </ToggleButton>
                            </ToggleButtonGroup>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the initial value for your variables on the useState definition? i.e const [valueOne, setValueOne] = useState('N'), this way it has an initial value you can populate before the api call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` doesn't set state until the next render, so you need to get `valueOne` and `valueTwo` from `data` directly when you have it, not call `setState` and then immediately try to access it.

```
Service.getValues()
        .then(data => {
            setValues(data)
            setValueOne(data.valueOne)
            setValueTwo(data.valueTwo)
        });
```

Or, add another `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //returns
    //Object { valueOne: "N", valueTwo: "Y" }
    Service.getValues()
        .then(data => setValues(data)
        );
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if (values.valueOne) {
        setValueOne(values.valueOne)
        setValueTwo(values.valueTwo)
    }
}, [values])
```

Comment: Just want to call out: OP is using an *array*, and they are trying to do property accesses, and your answer does copy that mistake.

Comment: he did state `getValues` returns "//Object { valueOne: "N", valueTwo: "Y" }"